# squiz matrix Show the search terms entered by the user

Tags: matrix, content-management-system

I aim doing a search feature with in squiz matrix what i am trying to do is to out put the users search term on to the results page using this:

Please note,  is the name of the field that was entered when it was created on the Search

%_query_terms%

This will show the terms the user entered into the search field.

my keyword line is:

```
%queries_search_query_query_terms%
```

Can anyone help

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your search asset and go to search fields screen. Note the name of your search field. Lets say it is `xyz`. You keyword would then be `%xyz_query_terms%`

OR

You can do this - `%globals_get_queries_search_query%`.

Answer (score 0):

@Anton Palitsyn was right in their answer. From the Squiz Matrix manuals it says

> %_query_terms%: where is the name of the field that was entered when it was created on the Search Fields screen. For example, if you entered the name Keyword, this will be %keyword_query_terms%. This will show the terms the user entered into the search field.

The Search Page Keyword Replacements can be found at http://manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net/search/appendices/keyword-replacements

You should check out http://manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net/search/chapters/search-page as it has all the info you need.

Comment: There is even a tutorial on how to create a Search Page on the site at http://manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net/search/examples/example-search-page.